# Multi-dimensional array preventing display of table rows and columns in the Matlab variable viewer

Tags: matlab

I have a table called `temp` and in the workspace I can see that it is a `5777x50` table. Yet, when I double click or use `openvar('temp')`, a new tab pops up in the `Variables` viewer with `Properties` in the first column, and `1x1 struct` in the second column.

If I type `temp` in the command window, the table prints in all its glory.

How do I see the table cells in the `Variables` viewer?

**EDIT 2015-12-04**: I have finally found a reproducible example and identified the problem. The Variables viewer is not displaying my tables when they contain an array with dimension greater than 2. For example:

```
tmp = table(ones(50,20, 20));
```

If I double click on `tmp` in my workspace, I see

[image: table not displaying properly when it contains multi dimensional array]

It would be good if it could show the same info as running the following command in the command window:

```
>> tmp(1:5, :)

      Var1      
________________

[1x20x20 double]
[1x20x20 double]
[1x20x20 double]
[1x20x20 double]
[1x20x20 double]
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I normally would, except I cannot replicate the problem except on this particular table. I cannot dump it either as the data is sensitive.

Comment: can you try temp2=temp{1} and then see if you can see temp2 in the variable viewer?

Comment: I'd suggest overwriting MATLAB's `openvar` function, even though I don't know if it's doable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to shadow openvar.m in your primary path, as suggested in a comment above. To do that, copy all the content of the original openvar.m into another openvar.m file, and place this new file in your path.

Now, add the following lines of code **on the end** of the new `openvar` function:

```
 v = evalin('base',name);
 if istable(v)
     v = table2struct(v);
     assignin('base','v', v);
     variable = com.mathworks.mlservices.WorkspaceVariableAdaptor('v');
     com.mathworks.mlservices.MLArrayEditorServices.openVariable(variable);
else
    evalin('base','clear v');
 end
```

The code will create a new variable v on the base workspace. If this variable is a table it'll open it on the editor as a struct, and if not it'll clear it.

This should suffice to display tables in a new struct variable (which I called `v`, but it should be straightforward to come up with a solution using `tempname`) in your variable editor, and it would give you the view you want.

Unfortunately this workaround will only give you a "fake" read access to your original table, but no "fake" write access, obviously. Another drawback is that now everytime you call openvar on a table you'll be redirected to this new "fake" v struct variable.

Creating a new function with another name `myopenvar` and calling `myopenvar('tmp')` would work too, but not when clicking on a variable displayed on your workspace.

(Tested on Matlab R2015b)

Comment: this is great thanks! Other possible ways of doing it could be to have all the non multidimensional arrays display as a table, and have a struct displaying the multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: true, that'd require just another clause on the if statement `if istable(v) && any(size(v) >= 50)` , or something like that..

Comment: I added this additional clause to the if statement: `& any(varfun(@(var) numel(size(var)), v, 'OutputFormat', 'Uniform') > 2)` It's crude, but basically causes tables with a variable containing more than two dimensions to be displayed using your method, otherwise, display as a normal table.

Comment: cool that it worked. I tried to fix the solution using `tempname` to avoid variable conflicts, but it turns that it pollutes the workspace more than anything else. No one calls a variable `v` anyway... we hope.

Comment: I would also recommend [submitting this as a bug](https://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) to The MathWorks so it eventually is fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

The values in your table can be visualized using the following:

```
openvar('tmp.Var1')
```

assuming that *tmp* is the name of the table.

In the `Variables` editor, in the struct `Properties`, you will find a cell `VariableNames` containing the char `Var1`. If your table contains other variables with other names, you can find them there. The issue is related to your data having more than 2 dimensions.